# Are *all* items limited to a certain number per game in Wasteland?

Tags: wasteland

My first introduction to RPG gaming was [Wasteland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasteland_%28video_game%29) on my old Commodore 64. Many of the items that are key to the story line (i.e. servo motors) only appear in a limited number during the game. However, I've always wondered if perhaps *all* items could be limited to a specific number per game. Here's why I ask...

I ran into a situation once when my game stagnated and I couldn't continue with the story line (I probably did something bad with one of the few servo motors in the game). As a result I was wandering around for an extended period of time revisiting every place I could to try and move the story forward. I began to notice that ammunition for all my weapons was running out at many of the shops, and enemies seemed to be dropping it less frequently, as if there was a limited supply of it.

Does anyone know if *all* items could be limited to an absolute number per game? Have you experienced the same thing, or perhaps managed to get a peek at the source code or have some other inside information about the availability of items in the game?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, only ammo is limited -- but you can definitely reach a point where the shops are out of out of 7.62mm, 9mm and .45.

Comment: Yeah, this is true. Shops don't restock, and have an inventory of at most 255 items of each kind. I'll try and dig up a citation; the whole PC version of the game has been disassembled and deconstructed in great detail. :)